# Balanced Graph Communities With Node Weights

Tags: graph-theory, python

I'm looking for where best to start on the following problem.

I have a graph of N nodes and each node as a weight. I need to group all nodes into X groups such that the sum of weights in each group are approximately even and that each group is a connected component of the original graph.

After some simple searching I came across the lukes partitioning algorithm implemented in python.

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.lukes.lukes_partitioning.html#networkx.algorithms.community.lukes.lukes_partitioning

This is approximately what I am looking for but performance feels slow for the size of the graph I am working with.

Do you have any potentially better ideas that worked for you?

Comment: Are you looking for an exact algorithm or an approximation? What graph sizes are you working with? What values of X are desired?

Comment: An approximation would be good enough. I am working with a graph that is approximately 10000 nodes in size. X should act as a controllable parameter ideally, but failing that I'd like X = 52.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank so much for the pastebin link, I managed to write my own code as well. Its not nearly as neat and efficient as Stevens.

https://pastebin.com/a21v2Nxz

I still think you are miss understanding my problems with the algorithm

I entirely believe it will colour each node without stopping

My main issue is its not guaranteed or even likely the colouring will be balanced.

Imagine a line graph with uniform weightage, and your random choice of starting classes is the first k nodes on the line graph.

Hopefully I am correct in saying that the only colour capable of growing in size in that situation is the which ever colour is the final colour (i.e. the kth colour on the line graph)

A situation like the simple graph below, where there are 4 coulours and n nodes in the line graph.

red - blue - green - yellow - null - null - ... - null

The solution to this problem I figured was a montecarlo like approach. The algorithm runs fast enough that you can do it many times, and choose which one is the best of all the attempts. That's the main addition to my code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Lee - it seems like what you wrote here is (at least in part) a continuation of the discussion in the comments below Steven's answer. I think it would be better if this second answer would stick to addressing your original question. (Readers should be able to understand your post without studying the other answer or its commentary.)

Answer (score 0):

If the graph is a complete graph, this problem reduces to the '[multiway partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning)', which is NP-hard.  If G is a tree, the problem can probably be solved efficiently with dynamic programming.

In the general case, I believe that making the partitions roughly equal in sum is harder than having all partition classes to be connected.

Since the order of your graph is very large, I would suggest a greedy approximation algorithm (explained with the terminology of 'colorings' in stead of partitions):

- Start by choosing $X$ vertices at random. These are the initial color-classes.
- As long as there are uncolored vertices, color a new vertex that produces the minimal-weight color class.
  That is: among all uncolored vertices $v$ that are adjacent to a colored vertex: consider coloring $v$ with a color of any of its neighbors. Choose this $v$ and the color in such a way that the resulting color class has minimal weight among all considered choices.

  Or more formally; for each uncolored node consider the function:
  $f(v) = \min_{C_i \sim v}{weight(C_i) + weight(v)}$
  Then choose $v$ with minimal $f$ and color it in the appropriate color.

Implementing this naively gives an $O(n^3)$ algorithm which should be doable for your $10000$ nodes. But with the appropriate data structures, better time complexities are possible.

Afterwards you could run a meta-heuristic to improve the solution locally, if you want to. I would suggest to keep the connectedness in tact at all time. That is: choose to recolor vertices on the boundary between color classes.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input, I'm working on an implementation in code. One question I do have is how to solve a situation where the minimal colour class has no neighbours that are uncoloured (e.g. the minimal weight partition is entirely surrounded by other partitions)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the algorithm. I check every uncoloured node and every colour it could receive.  Then among all those options I choose the vertex-colour pair that produces the smallest-weight colour class. Since there is always at least one option, the algorithm cannot get stuck. I guess your version of the algorithm could produce good colourings as well. If you are stuck then just go to the second-lowest colour class.

Comment: Its not about getting stuck and not colouring in every node, it is about a certain colour getting stuck without neighbouring uncoloured node and being a smaller class than the other classes. I'm still researching solutions and found that a Monte Carlo like method for this problem could also work

Comment: I'm still not sure if you interpreted the algorithm correctly.  Here is an implementation I made in Sage (which should be roughly equal to Python code). This algorithm can only get stuck if you graph is disconnected, and not all connected components contain a coloured initial vertex. https://pastebin.com/GeQHLQkw